# How to add Specific Class to Each Drupal Menu Anchor

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am developing a website using drupal and i need to know about how to add link to drupal menu anchor.

For example:

- i have a drupal menu: user menu. Within user menu, i have several list of links, let's say: A, B, C, D.
- Then, i want to add class/id for each of the anchor, such as: `<a href = "AAA" class = "A">A</a>`

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [Menu Attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module.

> This simple module allows you to specify some additional attributes for menu items such as id, name, class, style, and rel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not satisfied with the module option, you could also have a look at the [this](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7#comment-11474). It works the same with many other templating things in drupal so understanding it really can't do any harm ;)